# In OCI Java sdk, how to retrieve the information abou the URL of ML user, APEX user

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-autonomous-db, oci-java-sdk

I create an Autonomous database instance and database user, APEX user, Machine learning users via the OCI java SDK API. However, i can not find  API which allow me to retrieve the URL for these users. Any help? or i have to sign-in to my OCI account console to get them?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please specify which API did you use to create the users and what is the URL for? Right now there is no API to retrieve the URL for a specific user.

Comment: The "get database" API would give you the list of URLs for all the tools. https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/database/20160918/AutonomousDatabase/GetAutonomousDatabase